# If "Part[Digits].rar" Exists In Filename

Tags: python, regex, rename

So I'm looking to develop a script to return a duple with filenames and extensions so I can alter the filenames (capitalize, remove dots, dashes, etc.) in the name, then just add the extension and be good to go (at some point I'm hoping to throw this into something with a GUI).

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is, but I'd like to have it so it takes the extension (the last .ext) unless the filename ends in "part[any number of digits, any number of zeros from 1-any number].rar" then it takes the last two parts as the "extension".

I'm not set on this specific methodology.  However, I do need it to integrate into the current script (integrate into the same script as I'll be using for everything else) and I know it needs to end with me having a duple name, ext pair.

My Current Code:

```
import os, shutil, re
def rename_file (original_filename):
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(original_filename)    
    name = re.sub(r"\'", r"", name) # etc...more of these...
    new_filename = name + extension
    try:
        # moves files or directories (recursively)
        shutil.move(original_filename, new_filename)
    except shutil.Error:
        print ("Couldn't rename file %(original_filename)s!" % locals())
[rename_file(f) for f in os.listdir('.') if not f.startswith('.')]
```

How do I make this put "part[digits]" with the .rar as part of the "ext" instead of as part of the name?

Comment: How do I add the "part[digits]" to the extension instead of the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a regular expression instead of using `splitext`:

```
m = re.search(r'(.*?)((part\[\d+\])?\.rar)', original_filename)
name, ext = m.groups()[:2]
```

So, for example:

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(.*?)((part\[\d+\])?\.rar)', 'name_part[23].rar')
>>> m.groups()[:2]
('name_', 'part[23].rar')
```

Or

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(.*?)((part\[\d+\])?\.rar)', 'name_no_parts.rar')
>>> m.groups()[:2]
('name_no_parts', '.rar')
```

This assumes that the extension is actually `.rar`.  It's easy to tweak the regex if this is not the case though.

Comment: Thank you, but can you let me know how to tweak it to work with all extensions??

Comment: Simply change the "rar" to ".*".  There are still some corner cases which will fail (e.g. what happens if the filename is just ".rar"?), but you will have to decide how you want to deal with them, and if you even need to.  This looks like its probably a utility script for personal use, in which case corner cases might not be a problem.

Comment: I suggest you read http://docs.python.org/library/re.html for help on regular expressions.